# Changing color of rows in datagrid from itemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, colors

In my datagrid i have rows that represent different colors.
in rgb form.

What I want to do basically is to set the color on each row to that color that the item represents.

So i want to loop trough the rows and set the color based on the item it holds.

My models looks like this:

```
public class ColorModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _GreenValue;
    private int _RedValue;
    private int _BlueValue;

    public int GreenValue
    {
        get { return _GreenValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_GreenValue != value)
            {
                _GreenValue = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GreenValue"));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public int RedValue
    {
        get { return _RedValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_RedValue != value)
            {
                _RedValue = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RedValue"));
            }
        }
    }


    public int BlueValue
    {
        get { return _BlueValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_BlueValue != value)
            {
                _BlueValue = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BlueValue"));
            }
        }
    }

    public SolidColorBrush GetColor()
    {
        Color res = new Color();
        res = Color.FromRgb(Convert.ToByte(RedValue), Convert.ToByte(GreenValue), Convert.ToByte(BlueValue));
        var result = new SolidColorBrush(res);
        return result;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I have a load method that initializes the data to the grid.

```
    private void Load()
    {
        var colorList = _Context.ColorMix.ToList();
        foreach (var item in colorList)
        {
            var res = Color.FromRgb(Convert.ToByte(item.RedValue), Convert.ToByte(item.GreenValue), Convert.ToByte(item.BlueValue));
            var result = new SolidColorBrush(res);
            var dr = new DataGridRow();
            dr.Item = item;
            dr.Background = result;
            myColorGrid.Items.Add(dr);
        }
        dataGrid = myColorGrid;
    }
```

The problem is that the item doesn't show. Only the color.
So it becomes like stripes with different colors.
I need the item also to be shown :P

Comment: And how do you want the item to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Brush` property to your `ColorModel`:

```
public Brush Brush => GetColor();
```

Set the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to the `colorList`:

```
private void Load()
{
    myColorGrid.ItemsSource = _Context.ColorMix.ToList();
    dataGrid = myColorGrid;
}
```

And use an `ItemContainerStyle` to bind the `Background` property of the row to the `Brush` property of the `ColorModel`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myColorGrid">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Brush}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Appreaciate it